# Is no need to install mariadb-client?

Tags: mariadb

Install mariadb in my debian:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Now i can connect the mariadb without installing mariadb-client:

```
 mariadb -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Maybe it is no need to install mariadb-client,why some webpage write as below?

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse mariadb-server with mariadb-client.

[mariadb-client](https://mariadb.com/docs/server/connect/clients/mariadb-client/) is a tool which is command-line based that is used for communication and interaction between the client and the MariaDB server.

> Maybe it is no need to install mariadb-client,why some webpage write
> as below?

See [mariadb Command-Line Client](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-command-line-client/) to create an idea for what mariadb-client is used for.

For example

To restore a backup created with mariadb-dump, use the mariadb client to import the dump:

`mariadb db_name < backup-file.sql`

See [mariadb-dump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-dump/) which is part of the mariadb-client as well.

---

Conclusion

If you choose another tool to connect to MariaDB sever , such as SQLyog you do not need mariadb-client.

I prefer to use the command line to manage the db and that's why I choose to install mariadb-client.